# How to use addClass function to a pseudo :before on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a `slideDown` feature that when you click on the title a new section slides down. When only the title is shown (the user hasn't clicked on it yet) I have a plus symbol. Then when they click on the title, I want the `background-image` to show a minus icon, indicating that the section has collapsed.

I am populating the image with the pseudo `:before`. In my javascript I am trying to get the minus symbol to take the plus' position with the `addClass` function by adding the class `opened`. However, my attempt is failing. This is where I try to add the class:

`.infoTitles:before.open`

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('.faqBlock').click(function() {
  var relative = $(this);
  if (!relative.hasClass('opened')) {
    $('.opened').removeClass('opened').next('.infoFaqContainer').slideUp(500);
    relative.addClass('opened').next('.infoFaqContainer').slideDown();
    $('.infoTitles:before').addClass('opened'); //this is where I am adding the class for the icon
  } else {
    relative.removeClass('opened').next('.infoFaqContainer').slideUp(500);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.faqTitle {
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.faqCont {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #2E393F;
}
.faqBlock {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.infoTitles {
 color: #2E393F;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.infoTitles:before {
 content: '';
 vertical-align: bottom;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
 background-image: url('https://www.colourbox.com/preview/5697410-icon-plus-black.jpg');
 background-size: 15px 15px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 display: block;
}
.infoTitles:before.open {
 content: '';
 vertical-align: bottom;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
 background-image: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/minus-big-512.png');
 background-size: 15px 15px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 display: block;
}
.infoFaqContainer {
 display: none;
}
.infoFaqInner {
 padding: 0 5px 40px 5px;
}
.faqDesc {
 font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 /*letter-spacing: .1rem;*/
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: #2E393F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="weddingInfoBlock">
<div class="wInfoBlockCont">
  <span class="wIBCTitle">FAQ's</span>
  <div class="faqCont">
    <div class="faqBlock">
      <div class="infoTitles">Title</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="infoFaqContainer">
      <div class="infoFaqInner">
        <p class="faqDesc">
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you used the wrong class in your style rule - the class is `opened` not `open`

2) the class is not added to the pseudo element which is how your css is structured - it's added to the parent.

Basically the rule needs to change from:

```
.infoTitles:before.open {
```

to

```
.opened .infoTitles:before {
```

Complete snippet below:

```js
$('.faqBlock').click(function() {
  var relative = $(this);
  if (!relative.hasClass('opened')) {
    $('.opened').removeClass('opened').next('.infoFaqContainer').slideUp(500);
    relative.addClass('opened').next('.infoFaqContainer').slideDown();
    $('.infoTitles:before').addClass('opened'); //this is where I am adding the class for the icon
  } else {
    relative.removeClass('opened').next('.infoFaqContainer').slideUp(500);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.faqTitle {
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.faqCont {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #2E393F;
}
.faqBlock {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.infoTitles {
 color: #2E393F;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.infoTitles:before {
 content: '';
 vertical-align: bottom;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
 background-image: url('https://www.colourbox.com/preview/5697410-icon-plus-black.jpg');
 background-size: 15px 15px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 display: block;
}
.opened .infoTitles:before {
 content: '';
 vertical-align: bottom;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
 background-image: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/minus-big-512.png');
 background-size: 15px 15px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 display: block;
}
.infoFaqContainer {
 display: none;
}
.infoFaqInner {
 padding: 0 5px 40px 5px;
}
.faqDesc {
 font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 /*letter-spacing: .1rem;*/
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: #2E393F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="weddingInfoBlock">
<div class="wInfoBlockCont">
  <span class="wIBCTitle">FAQ's</span>
  <div class="faqCont">
    <div class="faqBlock">
      <div class="infoTitles">Title</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="infoFaqContainer">
      <div class="infoFaqInner">
        <p class="faqDesc">
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Perfect, thanks! I appreciate the explanation, too.

Answer (score 0):

Used the **opened** class on **faqBlock** div top target the inner icon.
i.e. When **faqBlock** has no **opened** class,show the plus icon in the child selector, and when **faqBlock** has **opened** class show the minus icon
Add this to us css

```
 .faqBlock .infoTitles:before {
    content: '';
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-image: url('https://www.colourbox.com/preview/5697410-icon-plus-black.jpg');
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.faqBlock.opened .infoTitles:before {
    content: '';
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/minus-big-512.png');
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/126587/)